# How to keep field's annotation with proguard at runtime

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm working on an Android App. The application works like a charm until I tried to obfuscate the code with Proguard.

```java
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.NotEmpty;

public class TaccuinoFragment extends Fragment {

    private TaccuinoViewModel mViewModel;

    @NotEmpty(messageResId = R.string.error_campo_obbligatorio)
    TextInputLayout titoloLayout;

}
```

The `gradle` configuration:

```
release {
  signingConfig signingConfigs.config
  zipAlignEnabled true
  minifyEnabled true
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), System.getenv("GRADLE_PROGUARD_CONFIG_FILE"), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

I tried the following Proguard's configuration:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {  @com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.** <fields>;}
```

How can I keep the `NotEmpty` annotation at runtime? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

`-keepattributes *Annotation*`

Comment: Like this `-keepattributes @com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.**`?

Comment: Nope, just `*Annotation*`, However if you are using gradle, you may need to put single quotes around annotation `'*Annotation*'`